# Android FCM push logs

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I want to see all the logs of push notifications received on my android device. I'm sending the FCM token of my device to my backend server, and the push is sent using PHP code to my device.

Does firebase console provide any statistics/logs of all push received for the specific device?

Answer (score 1):

Firebase doesn't keep the track of device-specific notifications.

Instead, what you can do is while sending notifications from the back-end, just keep the track of notifications sent to specific devices by storing this data on your database, and then you can fetch it on your android device.

Answer (score 0):

you could do kinda of that. Using analytics labels (only with FCM API v1) you can see on the firebase console the stats about received messages. If you use a specific label only for your device, you will know how many notification have been received by that specific device.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/understand-delivery?platform=android